# User group changed event

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, wmi

Is there any way to know when user group members list has changed? I've tried to use `WMI` query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group'
```

But it doesn't work (the event never fires). Maybe there is a `Win32` event that is being fired when a user group members are changed?

**UPDATE 1**

`__InstanceOperationEvent` doesn't work either. I need to get the event when the group policy is applied and a user is added/removed from a user group on the local machine to display this change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems which the [`__InstanceModificationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event is not trigger in this class, but you can use these others  events.

To detect changes use the [`__InstanceOperationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event,

```
Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group'
```

To detect the creation of a group use the [`__InstanceCreationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event,

```
Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group'
```

To detect the deletion of a group use the [`__InstanceDeletionEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event

```
Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group';
```